# Moving ES data to a new server using cluster replication

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my first posting, and my first ES problem so please bear with me.
I'm trying to move from an existing ES cluster to a new cluster.
The existing indexes are the same, and they both exist on the same subnet.
It ocured to me that if I simply repoint my new cluster nodes to the old cluster, the data would replicate for me.
Then I simply remove the old nodes from the cluster, shut the whole thing down, and rename the cluster on my new nodes.

Are there any caveats or gotchas to this method?
One extra point - I am adding a new index to the new cluster, but it's existence shouldn't matter as it will be replicated to the old nodes.

Answer (score 1):

It should work exactly as your describe Glenn.  The one thing I would consider is if your nodes are across subnets any potential Firewalls that may come into play.  I would also suggest doing the work in this order

1. Bring new nodes into the cluster.
2. Increase replicas (if needed).
3. Disable old nodes one by one ensure enough time to replicate shards.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the point above (unable to comment) once you have shards moved onto your new node, you can disable allocation to a node you wish to fade out of the cluster

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-allocation.html